# how to check a method override or not

Tags: java

i have two question 
1 overriding 
2 compile time binding
hi i want to know that how i can check that sh() become override

is method argument play any role in method overriding ?

why we say that static method bind at compile time but actually static method allocate memory at the class loading time ?
when i  use javac tool that means i use compiler and i compile a java file ,so that moment static memory not allocate ,static memory allocate a class loading time 
then why say that static method use compile  time binding

is class loading time same as compile time ? 
i am confuse

i know here method signature is different so no override here than what actually happens here explain

```
class A
    {
        void sh(char x){
        System.out.println("value of x :  "+x);
        }
    }
    class B extends A
    {
        public void sh(int x)
        {
            System.out.println("value of x"+x);
        }
    }
    class C
    {
        public static void main(String...Aa) /* ??? */
        {
            A a1=new B();
            //a1.show();
            a1.sh('a');
            a1.sh(10);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using an IDE, a good trick is to add `@Override` over the method.

Comment: Use `@Override` annotation to be sure you actually overriding a method of the Base class :-) After adding this notation, try to change the name of the method, a compile time error will be generated.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) states

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, 
>   declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - Either:
>
>   - m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same
>       package as C, or
>   - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2),
>       such that m3 overrides m2.
> - Moreover, if m1 is not abstract, then m1 is said to implement any and
>     all declarations of abstract methods that it overrides.

The definition for [`subsignature` is here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2). You ask

> is method argument play any role in method overriding ?

According to the above, yes very much so. You signatures have to match. In other words

```
public void sh(int x)
```

is not overriding

```
void sh(char x){
```

> why we say that static method bind at compile time but actually static
>   method allocate memory at the class loading time ?

At compile time, a method call is resolved on the static or declared type of the reference. In other words, the program won't compile if the type doesn't declare such a method. For `static` methods. If the method is `static`, then the method is immediately resolved and bound to the type it is called on. If it is an `instance` method, binding is resolve dynamically (late-binding) with polymorphism.

None of this has anything to do with class loading or allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you're asking.  However, when `B` extends `A`, `B` will also inherit the `sh(char x)` method.  The `sh(int x)` method does not override this, since the argument type is different.  So an object of class `B` will have two different methods named `sh`.

In your code, though, you declared `a1` to be of type `A`.  Even though it will (at run time) refer to an object of type `B`, as far as the compiler knows it is still type `A`.  Therefore, the methods you can apply to this object are the ones declared in `A` (and its *superclasses*, if it had any, but it doesn't, other than `Object`).  The only method you have (besides the `Object` methods) is `sh(char x)`.

So when you say

```
a1.sh('a');
a1.sh(10);
```

the compiler will treat this as if the argument is a `char`, since the only method it will look at is the one that takes a `char` argument.  This means that `a1.sh(10)` will call the `sh` in `A` with "character 10" as an argument--EDIT: no it won't; I tried it, and the compiler won't let me convert 10 to a `char` automatically.